# Передача символов из переменной в аргументы функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

К примеру есть переменная `hi = ['hello', 'world']` и функция

```
def sayHi(*args):
    for i in args:
        print(i)
```

Надо чтобы вместо вызова `sayHi('hello', 'world')` был вызов с помощью переменной. Конструкция
`sayHi(hi[0],hi[1])` не подойдет т.к. в переменной может быть неопределенное кол-во элементов.

Comment: `sayHi(*hi) ` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать **распаковку последовательностей**

`sayHi(*hi)`